# Unable to link Nvstreamdemux to rtph264pay element using PyGObject

Tags: gstreamer, pygobject, nvidia-deepstream

Please provide complete information as applicable to your setup.

**• Hardware Platform (Jetson / GPU)** Jetson

**• DeepStream Version** 5.0

**• JetPack Version (valid for Jetson only)** 4.4

**• TensorRT Version** 7.0

**• NVIDIA GPU Driver Version (valid for GPU only)**
**• Issue Type( questions, new requirements, bugs)** questions
**• How to reproduce the issue ? (This is for bugs. Including which sample app is using, the configuration files content, the command line used and other details for reproducing)**

```
print("Linking demux to the rtppayload in the Pipeline \n")
    for i in range(number_of_sources):
       demux_srcpad = streamdemux.get_request_pad("src_%u"%i)
       if not demux_srcpad:
           sys.stderr.write("Unable to get the src pad of streamdemux \n")
       sinkpad = rtppayload_list[i].get_static_pad("sink")
       if not sinkpad:
           sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get sink pad of rtppayload \n")
       demux_srcpad.link(sinkpad)
```

**• Requirement details( This is for new requirement. Including the module name-for which plugin or for which sample application, the function description)**

I am trying to create source pads for the nvstreamdemux element at run-time and link to several rtph264pay elements which reside inside the list : rtppayload_list. The above given code results in the following error:
gi.overrides.Gst.LinkError:

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you can only link element and pads that are compatible with each other.

in you case, `nvstreamdemux` outputs raw data in NV12 or RGBA format at its source pad whereas `rtph264pay` takes h264 encoded stream at its input sink pad. So these two are incompatible with each other.

You need to link `nvstreamdemux` to some element that encodes raw data into h264 like `nvv4l2h264enc` and then in turn link `nvv4l2h264enc` to `rtph264pay`.

so your pipeline should look like
`nvstreamdemux`->`nvv4l2h264enc`->`rtph264pay`

Comment: yes, I figured that out after reading the documentation. Thanks anyway.